# non-decreasing by young's inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose that $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx=1 $ and $\int_0^{\infty}e^{kx}f(x)dx<\infty$ for some $k>0 $. Prove $(\int_0^{\infty}x^tf(x)dx)^{\frac{1}{t}}$ is non-decreasing in t (Hint: Use young's inequality).I want to follow the hint,but i don't know how to apply young's inequality.Can someone give more hint or a complete proof?

Comment: There are a lot of $f$ that satisfy your hypothesis for which $\int_0^\infty x^t f (x)dx $ is negative, so it doesn't make sense in general to take the $1/t $-power of this quantity. Are you sure that you didn't miss any hypothesis?

Comment: I think it should be added that f is  non-negative

Comment: I can't see how this follows from Young's inequality (by the way, which one of the three?). However, it is a simple consequence of Jensen's inequality (and you can also get rid of the useless condition $\int_0^\infty e^{kx}f(x)dx<\infty$)

Comment: I think that we can prove Holder's inequality by young's inequality.For $t_1<t_2$ we take $p=\frac{t_2}{t_1}$ and $q=\frac{t_2}{t_2-t_1}$. By using Holder's inequality ,we will have $(\int_0^{\infty}x^{t_1}f(x)dx)^{\frac{1}{t_1}}<(\int_0^{\infty}x^{t_2}f(x)dx)^{\frac{1}{t_2}}$

Comment: Is it also another possible approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Young's inequality says $ab \leq \frac {a^{p}} p + \frac {b^{p}} q$ if $a,b \geq 0$,$1<p<\infty $ and $\frac 1 p + \frac 1 q =1$. Let $0<t<s$ and  denote by $c$ the number $(\int_0^{\infty } x^{s}f(x)\, dx)^{t/s}$. Let $p=\frac s t$, $q=\frac s {s-t}$. Apply Young's inequality with $a=\frac {x^{t}} c$ and $b=1$. You will get $\frac {x^{t}} c \leq \frac {x^{s}} {pc^{p}}+\frac 1 q$. Mulitiply by $f(x)$ and integrate to get $ \frac {\int_0^{\infty}x^{t}f(x)\, dx } c \leq \frac 1 p +\frac 1 q =1$ (where we used the fact that $c^{p}$ in the denominator cancels with $\int_0^{\infty } x^{s} f(x)\, dx$). Hence $ {\int_0^{\infty}x^{t}f(x)\, dx } \leq c=(\int_0^{\infty } x^{s}f(x)\, dx)^{t/s}$. This gives $ ({\int_0^{\infty}x^{t}f(x)\, dx })^{1/t} \leq c=(\int_0^{\infty } x^{s}f(x)\, dx)^{1/s}$ which is what we want to prove.